# ¿Cómo hacer para que df.dtype devuelva el tipo de todas las columnas en python?

Tags: python, dataframe

Estoy intentando ver de qué tipo es cada columna de mi dataframe en python, por lo que ejecuto lo siguiente: `df.dtype`

Lo que me devuelve (en spyder):

```
Out[7]: 
ID                      int64
NUMERO_CUESTIONARIO     int64
OLA                     int64
AEROPUERTO_ORIGEN      object
PAIS_DESTINO           object
 
SITUACION_LABORAL       int64
INGRESOS                int64
PERSONAS_HOGAR          int64
TRIMESTRE              object
PESO                   object
Length: 175, dtype: object
```

Pero mi dataframe contiene muchas más columnas de las que aparece en la salida, así que me gustaría que la salida mostrara todos las columnas y no solo las 10 que aparecen en la salida

¿Cómo puedo mostrar todas las columnas y sus tipos con `dtype`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observas menos columnas por la configuración que tiene pandas al importarla. Puedes al momento de importar setear:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 200)
```

...y luego df.dtypes debería mostrar todas las columnas.